# gnuplot plot from string

Tags: string, plot, gnuplot

Is it possible to pass to plot data in a string?

I mean do something like this:

```
plot "09-13-2010,2263.80 09-14-2010,2500" using 1:2 with lines
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do something like:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%y"     
plot "< echo '09-13-2010,2263.80 09-14-2010,2500' | tr ' ' '\n' | tr ',' ' '" using 1:2 with lines
```

Where the `<` character indicates to Gnuplot that we want our input from the output of a command. Gnuplot separates records with a newline. Groups of records are separated by a blank record. Within a record, the default column separator is a space. In the above example `tr` is used to split your data into lines, and the rewrite the lines into records.

Another way to plot your data from a string is to use the "-" input specifier, and then load the data in from the command line. A program could easily emit the following:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%y"
plot '-' using 1:2 with lines
09-13-2010 2263.80
09-14-2010 2500
e
```

Your best bet is to use an input file like:

```
09-13-2010 2263.80
09-14-2010 2500
```

Assuming the input file is named `mydata.txt`, you can then plot it with the commands:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%y"
plot 'mydata.txt' using 1:2 with lines
```

All the examples above give you something like:
[image]

If you want to plot two data series using dates and the `-' input you could do the following:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%y"
plot '-' using 1:2  title "Series 1" with lines,'-' using 1:2 title "Series 2" with lines
09-13-2010 2263.80
09-14-2010 2500
e
09-13-2010 2500
09-14-2010 2263.80
e
```

The previous example gives:
[image]

Comment: And is there a way to plot this way:
plot '-' using 1:2 with lines...
two functions?
I trie to separate this with a coma but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to set a full using spec for each function. Check out `help datafile' in the Gnuplot help system.  I've added an example above.