# gnuplot : how to save datafile values into a variable (with condition)?

Tags: file, variables, save, gnuplot

I use Gnuplot and I would like to save values of a datafile into a variable with condition.
For example, I have the following datafile 'example.dat':

```
columnl   column2
   5        7.0
   3        4.0
   7        6.0
```

In my gnuplot script, I would like to be able to write:

```
variable = " in the file 'example.dat' ($1)==5 ? $2 : 1/0 "
```

which would be here the same as:

```
variable = 7.0
```

of course the value depends on the datafile.

So is it possible?

If not, is it possible without condition?

Comment: probably one answer from here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540614/reading-dataset-value-into-a-gnuplot-variable-start-of-x-series?rq=1

Comment: You could use `stats 'example.dat' using ($1 == 5 ? $2 : 0); variable = STATS_sum`, but that requires, that the value you want to extract is uniquely defined, i.e. there is exactly one row which matches the condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I worked around the problem:

```
A=""
plot file u (A=A.sprintf(' %g',$2), $1):2
```

All the entries from column 2 will be written to A, which you can access then via:

```
word(A,i)
```

where i is the number of the raw (starting at 1)
words(A) gives you the total length.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, you can workaround the limitation of Christoph's solution which allows only *one* occurrence of your check value in your data.

Two versions which return the corresponding value:

1. for the **first** occurrence of your check value
2. for the **last** occurrence of your check value

The example below works for gnuplot >=5.0.0, but if you use a file instead of the datablock `$Data` it will also work for gnuplot 4.6.0 (version at the time of OP's question).

**Code:**

```
### extract values via condition
reset

$Data <<EOD
  5   7.0
  3   4.0
  7   6.0
  5   1.0
  4   2.0
  5   3.0
  2   1.0
EOD

check = 5   # value to check

v=NaN
stats $Data u ($1==check ? v==v ? NaN : v=$2 : 0) nooutput
print sprintf("Value for first occurrence of %g: %g",check,v)

v=NaN
stats $Data u ($1==check ? v=$2 : 0) nooutput
print sprintf("Value for last occurrence of %g:  %g",check,v)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
Value for first occurrence of 5: 7
Value for last occurrence of 5:  3
```