# gnuplot xvalue of maximum of y

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

I have a file made of three columns, x, y1 and y2. I need to know the value at which y2 has a maximum. To find the maximum of y2 is easy:

```
stats 'test2-EDB.dat' u 3
```

from which I know that the y2 has a maximum on the 6779th line of the file

```
STATS_index_max = 6779.0
```

However, what I need it the x value at the 6779th line of the file. Do you have any suggestions? Which optimally are platform independent?

The solution which I have found here ([Reading dataset value into a gnuplot variable (start of X series)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540614/reading-dataset-value-into-a-gnuplot-variable-start-of-x-series)) was:

```
at(file, row, col) = system( sprintf("awk -v row=%d -v col=%d 'NR == row {print $col}' %s", row, col, file) )
file="test2-EDB.dat" ; row=STATS_index_max ; col=1
c=at(file,row,col)
```

However, I doubt that this solutions works without any problems also on windows (no idea, I'm not using it).

With best regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `every` for the `stats` command to get the x-value:

```
stats 'test2-EDB.dat' u 3
stats 'test2-EDB.dat' u 1 every ::STATS_index_max::STATS_index_max
print sprintf("x-value is %e", STATS_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it shorter and easier:

```
stats 'test2-EDB.dat' u 1:3 nooutput
print sprintf("Maximum at x=%g y=%g", STATS_pos_max_y, STATS_max_y)
```

Should work with gnuplot>=4.6.0 (March 2012)