# gnuplot for which x the y is maximum

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

In Gnuplot, I want to obtain from `stats` the value of `x` where the `y` attains maximum. The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789852/gnuplot-xvalue-of-maximum-of-y) uses a very clever trick. This solution only works without setting `xrange`. If I have a spike in data at the begining which i want to avoid, I want to `set xrange [200:1000]` and then do `stats data using 1:3 nooutput` will produce `STATS_index_max_y` for which the first value above 200 has index 0. When this is used in `every` the value of the `x` is incorrect.

Is there an easy "gnuplot" only way to get around this?

Comment: Please give a minimal example! Do you want the value of x or the index of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the accepted answer to your linked question does is so complicated.

If you want to find ymax and the corresponding x-value simply do:

```
stats [200:1000] "myFile.dat" u 1:3 nooutput
print STATS_pos_max_y, STATS_max_y
```

After having carried out a `stats` command, type `show var STATS` in the console and you will see all the variables which have been calculated.